# Why Hibernate inlines Integer parameter list passed to JPA Criteria Query?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, prepared-statement, criteria-api

I am building a query using JPA Criteria API. When I created two restriction predicates using `javax.persistence.criteria.Path#in(Collection<?>)` method the generated SQL query was a little bit different than I excpected.

The first predicate which was build over `int` attribute produced SQL with all elements of parameter collection inlined: `in (10, 20, 30)`.

The second predicate which was build over `String` attribute produced parametrized SQL: `in (?, ?, ?)`.

Let me show:

Entity:

```
@Entity
public class A {
    @Id 
    private Integer id;
    private int intAttr;
    private String stringAttr;
    //getter/setters
}
```

Query:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<A> q = cb.createQuery(A.class);
Root<A> root = q.from(A.class);
q.where(
    root.get("intAttr").in(Arrays.asList(10, 20, 30)),
    root.get("stringAttr").in(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"))
);
entityManager.createQuery(q).getResultList();
```

Log:

```
select
    a0_.id as id1_0_,
    a0_.intAttr as intAttr2_0_,
    a0_.stringAttr as stringAt3_0_ 
from
    A a0_ 
where
    (
        a0_.intAttr in (
            10 , 20 , 30
        )
    ) 
    and (
        a0_.stringAttr in (
            ? , ? , ?
        )
    ) 
org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [a] 
org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [b] 
org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - [c]
```

My questions:

1. Why are elements of Integer list inlined directly to sql and elements of String list are handled as prepared statement parameters?
2. Is this feature Hibernate specific or is it guaranteed by JPA?
3. From DB perspective which of two should be preferred?
4. Is this int-yes string-no inlining somehow related to sql injection?
5. Is this somehow related to limitation of number of values in sql IN clause the RDMBS can process?
6. How to write a criteria query which will handle Integer parameter list the same way as String parameter list.

Comment: Really seems like a question for the Hibernate forums, don't you think?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Why are strings bound and numeric literals not bound?**

One should always do parameter binding for strings (as opposed to putting the literal in the query) to avoid SQL injection.

However, the real question, is why to insert the literal directly into the query instead of using binding.  The original reason was:

> So iirc the issue that lead me to use literals here had to do with
>   scale and operations. Meaning (again, iirc) some databases needed to
>   know type information to be able to properly handle something like ...
>   ? + ? ..., etc. So the choice was to either wrap all such params in
>   CAST function calls and hope/pray the db implemented a proper CAST
>   function or use literals. In the end I opted for the literal route
>   because, well, thats what the user asked for up front. Wrapping in
>   function calls will limit the databases ability to leverage indexes in
>   quite a few databases.

**Which is better for the db?**

It depends on the database and the query and likely won't make a huge difference.  For example, Oracle can only do certain partitions when the value is a literal, other databases can only do certain optimizations when the value is a bound parameter.  If it becomes an issue (e.g. you profile it and you know that is what is slowing you down) then just switch to the other method.

**Is this in the JPA spec?**

No.

**Is this related to the # of values allowed in an in statement?**

No.

**Can I have a numeric literal bound instead of inserted directly into the query**

Yes, but it is somewhat verbose.

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Foo> query = cb.createQuery(Foo.class);
Root<Foo> root = query.from(Foo.class);
ParameterExpression<Long> paramOne = cb.parameter(Long.class);
Predicate versionPredicate = root.get("bar").in(paramOne);
query.select(root).where(versionPredicate);
TypedQuery<Foo> typedQuery = getEntityManager().createQuery(query);
typedQuery.setParameter(paramOne, 1L);
```

That will use parameter binding for the long.  It is only one parameter but one could easily extrapolate from here for multiple parameters and helper methods could clean things up.

**References:**

Most of the reasoning is explained and discussed in [HHH-6280](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6280).
The particular method in question that does this rendering is [LiteralExpression.render](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-entitymanager/src/main/java/org/hibernate/jpa/criteria/expression/LiteralExpression.java).

Comment: *"One should always do parameter binding for strings (as opposed to putting the literal in the query) to avoid SQL injection."* - That's a good default recommendation, but "always" is wrong. There are good reasons to occasionally inline string literals as well. *"likely won't make a huge difference"* - Have you ever tried to recover from `cursor pin S wait on X` events in production because of severe execution plan cache contention? When your database has an execution plan cache, you will want bind variables wherever possible (and avoid highly dynamic `IN` lists, too, in Oracle)

Answer (score 6):

In issue [HHH-9576](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9576) a new parameter was added to fix this issue, applicable since version *5.2.12 (?)*

```
<property name="hibernate.criteria.literal_handling_mode" value="bind"/>
```

If you use this parameter you don't need the verbose solution proposed by Pace anymore.

From hibernate documentation of [literal_handling_mode](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/query/criteria/LiteralHandlingMode.html):

> This enum defines how literals are handled by JPA Criteria. By default (AUTO), Criteria queries uses bind parameters for any literal that is not a numeric value. However, to increase the likelihood of JDBC statement caching, you might want to use bind parameters for numeric values too. The BIND mode will use bind variables for any literal value. The INLINE mode will inline literal values as-is. To prevent SQL injection, never use INLINE with String variables. Always use constants with the INLINE mode.

Comment: life saver!  now the hibernate query cache is useful instead of hogging 1Gb of RAM for query plans that are never going to get reused.

Answer (score 1):

1. Because Strings can contain SQL and Integers cannot, there is no need to from a security aspect (SQL injection).
2. The JPA spec doesn't specify it as explicit as you would like it to be. It seems to be an implementation details.
3. Prepared statement parameters for String parameters. For int parameters it doesn't matter since they cannot be misused by hackers.
4. YES
5. You should look that up in the documentation of the specific database you're using. JPA does not care about such things.
6. Why? What are the benefits? Don't try to improve things when you don't know what you're improving.

Comment: The benefit is that it helps the Query Plan Cache of the database. If the query is the same but it has a variable passed as literal the database will have to create a new query plan every time the query is executed, which can slow down the execution.

Comment: Regarding 1): It's not that hard to properly escape inline string values such that SQLi will never be a problem. After all, this is a dynamic query builder, so it can handle this globally. 3): Incorrect, from a performance perspective. It does matter. Bind variables are the better default in the presence of a query plan cache, but occasionally, inline values should be preferred. 4) Can you back your assumption? I personally doubt it. It just seems like a bug. E.g. no such rationale was given in https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9576 5) It should 6) What made you assume that?

Comment: However, there is no benefit, and is *really* problematic if the "literal" in question is used to set orderBy().

There is also no benefit if the literal is an actual, constant literal (that never changes) and not a variable provided by a user.