# Hibernate specification not using parameters sql server

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have written a custom predicate that I make use of in a `JpaSpecificationExecutor` query. The generated SQL for this query does not make use of a parameter, and therefore the query cache has 2 entries (as the queries differ by 1 character!). Is the use of the aggregate function what is causing the difference I am seeing? (outlined below).

My application is using sqlserver 2012 for its database and I have monitored the queries via sqlserver management studio. The output of which I have observed making use of parameters for `billingType` and `recordedDate` but not `recordedValue`.

Below is the predicate code I have used:

```
Subquery<Entity> subQuery = query.subquery(Entity.class);
Root<Entity> subQueryRoot = subQuery.from(Entity.class);
subQuery.select(subQueryRoot.get("userId"));

Optional<Predicate> teamEquals = // Call to helper

Predicate isMinutes = builder.equal(subQueryRoot.get("billingType"), BillingType.MINUTES);
Predicate minutesDate = builder.greaterThan(subQueryRoot.get("recordedDate"), LocalDate.now().minus(Period.parse(params.getHoursPeriod())));
Predicate minutesThreshold = builder.greaterThan( subQueryRoot.get("recordedValue"), params.getHours() * 60 );
Predicate minutesRestriction = builder.and(isMinutes, minutesDate, minutesThreshold);

Predicate isDocuments = builder.equal(subQueryRoot.get("billingType"), BillingType.DOCUMENTS);
Predicate documentsDate = builder.greaterThan(subQueryRoot.get("recordedDate"), LocalDate.now().minus(Period.parse(params.getDocumentsPeriod())));
Predicate documentsThreshold = builder.greaterThan( subQueryRoot.get("recordedValue"), params.getDocuments() );
Predicate documentsRestriction = builder.and(isDocuments, documentsDate, documentsThreshold);

subQuery.where( builder.and(teamEquals.get(), builder.or( minutesRestriction, documentsRestriction ) ) );
return Optional.of(subQuery);
```

This results in 2 generated queries differing by 1 character.
E.g. (IN HQL) 
`SELECT * FROM User where id IN (SELECT userId FROM Entity WHERE  billingType = @p1 AND recordedDate > @p2 AND recordedValue > 0)`
vs.
`SELECT * FROM User where id IN (SELECT userId FROM Entity WHERE  billingType = @p1 AND recordedDate > @p2 AND recordedValue > 40)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like it is the following Hibernate bug https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9576

Also there appears to be a workaround documented at [Why Hibernate inlines Integer parameter list passed to JPA Criteria Query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36811521/why-hibernate-inlines-integer-parameter-list-passed-to-jpa-criteria-query)